# Recursion to print number by using return statement

Tags: java, recursion

I'm using recursion to print numbers until 2(number), and I'm passing zero(0) as input and recursively calling it until the number reaches 2.
I have tried this code, and it shows the correct output.

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        rec(0);
    }
    private static void rec(int num){
        if(num<=2){
            rec(++num);
        }
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

but I want to do this with the following way.

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        rec(0);
    }
    private static void rec(int num){
        if(num==2){
            return;
        }
        rec(++num);
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
2,1,0
```

but it shows:

```
2,1
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: When asking for free help at least take the time to correctly format and indent your code.

Comment: Fix indenting, please.

Comment: sorry I'm new to stackoverflow

Comment: Kindly, show me how indent the code? so that i care to upload next time.

Comment: @Coder1 "*..how indent the code?*" there are many sites which can "prettify/beautify/format/indent" your code online, but usually we let our IDEs do it for us. Each decent editor should have such tool like Eclipse, NetBeans, IntelliJ. If your editor doesn't have such tool, but it supports plugins there is usually someone who wrote plugin for that, search for it.

Answer (score 2):

`++num` increments `num`, which (as here) makes the code harder to understand.

Try calling `rec(num + 1);` instead.

You may find your terminating condition needs to be modified to:

```
if (num > 2)
```

Terminating conditions are usually the “do nothing” case, which is the case here.

Answer (score 2):

When you are calling `rec(++num);`, you are incrementing `num` before printing it out. So when you use `0` as input, by the time it prints `num` will have changed to `1`. When `num = 2` at the start of `rec()`, the print does not execute.

`rec(0)` prints `rec(1),1`

`rec(1)` prints `rec(2),2`

`rec(2)` prints nothing

Total output: `2,1`

Comment: Thanks for Answering but why it not prints zero(0)

Comment: @Coder1 "but why it not prints zero(0)" because when `num` holds `0` after `rec(++num)` it becomes `1` which is what `System.out.println(num);` after it prints. Don't use `rec(++num)` but `rec(num+1)` to pass incremented *value* without modifying `num` variable.

Comment: Edited answer to show how it outputs. Remember that `++num` is the same as `num = num + 1;`

Comment: After modifying to num+1 it gives 2,1

Comment: You are using `rec(num + 1)` but not `System.out.println(num + 1)`?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because `++num` doesn't just return `num + 1` it also modifies `num` like `num = num + 1`.

Your if statement is also backwards.

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    rec(0);
  }

  private static void rec(int num) {
    if (num < 2) {
      rec(num + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(num);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        rec(0);
    }

    private static void rec(int num){
        if(num <= 2){
            rec(num + 1);
        } else return;

        System.out.println(num);
    }

}
```

`++num` - prefixes increment, it means that it's incremented before `System.out.println(num);` was called. So, first, you check the case of recursion call. If it condition is false - get out of recursion. And when printing value.

When you are working with recursion, try to spread out nested blocks of code, when you will understand simpler.

Comment: `else return;` can be removed if you move `System.out.println(num);` inside `if(..)`.

Comment: ..or you don't even leave it outside of `if` if you change `<= 2` to `< 2`.

Comment: The Expected output is : 2,1,0

Comment: Thanks for replying